# angular component replacement feature

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the angular component replacement feature.

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="com"></li>
  <li class="com"></li>
</ul>
```

For complicated interface, if I want to make the middle `.com` "li" into a whole new component, and write this code like:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <com-component></com-component>
</ul>
```

How can I make sure that the finally compiled `html` is exactly what the original `html` template looks like?

It is not possible as far as I have searched from angular [docs](https://angular.io/docs).

In `angularjs`, there is `replacement` feature. For a "compiled" angular framework, this is bit of off-putting not to have this.

Comment: I think you want `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component.

Answer (score 0):

View Encapsulation is what you need as you want the styles to bleed in from the parent component to the child component.

> ViewEncapsulation.None - No Shadow DOM at all. Therefore, also no
>   style encapsulation. ViewEncapsulation.Emulated - No Shadow DOM but
>   style encapsulation emulation. ViewEncapsulation.Native - Native
>   Shadow DOM with all it’s goodness.

More on [**View Encapsulation**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/view)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute selector in the `com-component`.

```
@Component({
...
selector: '[com-component]'
})
```

And then, in the template, simply add `com-component` as an attribute to the li element instead of adding it as a new tag.

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li com-component></li>
</ul>
```